# How to add simple dom-element into ExtJS container?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.2

I want to add `Canvas` element into **ExtJS** `Container` element. But it accepts only `Ext.Component`, not any dom element.

Canvas create code:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

How to insert it into container, or I need to use another ext component? I need to have some resize logic for component, container have it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best way to do this is to create a component where the element is the canvas. This way, you get all the built in layout stuff for "free" basically.

```
new Ext.container.Container({
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: {
        xtype: 'component',
        autoEl: {
            tag: 'canvas'
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Is it possible to set id for this canvas ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Container's `update` method to put in raw HTML. Panel is a better object to use here because you can use its `html` constructor config parameter to just dump whatever HTML you want upon creation. Ex:

```
var panel = {
    xtype: 'panel',
    html: ['<div>',
        '<p>Hi!</p>',
        '</div>'].join("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 4):

[DomHelper](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.DomHelper) is useful here, e.g:

```
Ext.DomHelper.append(your_container.body, { tag: 'canvas' })
```

Answer (score 1):

you can add a panel to your container as your canvas container like:

```
Ext.getCmp('yourContainer').add(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: '<div id="canvasContainer"></div>'
}));
```

then add your stuff to it:

```
var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
$("#canvasContainer").appendChild(canvas);
```

or you can easily add your html element like:

```
Ext.getCmp('yourContainer').add(Ext.create('Ext.Panel', {
    html: '<canvas></canvas>'
}));
```