# How can i add an empty div to ext:Window

Tags: asp.net, extjs, aspxgridview, ext.net, aspx-user-control

> I want to add an empty div to ext:Window so that i can render a chart into that div and into that popup window.

```
<ext:Window>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extjs how to add html div as item](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56479460/extjs-how-to-add-html-div-as-item)

Comment: Not really, im just looking for an ext component that resembles a div in html, all i need to do is give it an id so i can load a chart onto it using js.

Comment: Maybe this is helpful. https://stackoverflow.com/a/22378072/2782393